# Angular 6 Manage Multiple Request in single Function

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addProfile(formValue) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const name of Object.keys(formValue)) {
      if (typeof formValue[name] === 'object') {
        if (name === 'education') {
          const eduList = formValue[name];
          for (const field of Object.keys(eduList)) {
            if (typeof eduList[field].school === 'string') {
              const clgname = eduList[field].school;
              this.addNewField(clgname, 'college').toPromise().then((data: any) => {
                eduList[field].school = {college_id: data.id, collegename: clgname};
                console.log(eduList[field].school, name);
                formData.append(name, JSON.stringify(formValue[name]));
              });
            } else {
              console.log('enter');
              formData.append(name, JSON.stringify(formValue[name]));
            }
          }
        } else if (name === 'experience') {
          const compList = formValue[name];
          for (const field of Object.keys(compList)) {
            if (typeof compList[field].company === 'string' && compList[field].company.trim() !== '') {
              const compname = compList[field].company;
              compList[field].company = {companyname: compname, company_id: null};
            }
          }
          formData.append(name, JSON.stringify(formValue[name]));
        } else if (name === 'course') {
          const corsList = formValue[name];
          for (const field of Object.keys(corsList)) {
            if (typeof corsList[field].coursename === 'string' && corsList[field].coursename.trim() !== '') {
              const corsname = corsList[field].coursename;
              corsList[field].coursename = {coursename: corsname, course_id: null};
            }
          }
          formData.append(name, JSON.stringify(formValue[name]));
        } else {
          formData.append(name, JSON.stringify(formValue[name]));
        }
      } else {
        formData.append(name, formValue[name]);
      }
    }
    return this.http.post('/api/user/addProfile.php', formData);
  }
  addNewField(fieldName, dbName) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fieldName', fieldName);
    formData.append('dbName', dbName);
    return this.http.post('/api/user/addNewField.php', formData);
  }
}
```

How To manage multiple http requset in `addProfile()` function when this function call `return this.http.post('/api/user/addProfile.php', formData);` `formData` submit before this http request is completing

```
 this.addNewField(clgname, 'college').toPromise().then((data: any) => {
                        eduList[field].school = {college_id: data.id, collegename: clgname};
                        console.log(eduList[field].school, name);
                        formData.append(name, JSON.stringify(formValue[name]));
                      });
```

How to wait before `addNewFieled()` completing the process then its all formData append to my last http request it is possible in angular 6 to wait until previous request is completed.

Comment: Is `addNewField()` an HTTP request? this seems so incorrect to call async functions in a loop.

Comment: You need to refactor `addProfile` function

Comment: Try to move out some part of code inside addProfile function to smaller functions as right now it is barely readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the `addNewField()` promise to finish before calling the next HTTP request (or doing other work on it)

the simplest way would be to use `Promise.all` and do something like

```
formData = new FormData()
promises = [];
// your business
promises.append(addNewField().toPromise().then(/* your old code*/))

return Promise.all(promises).then(this.http.post('/api/user/addProfile.php', formData))
```